# Multiform part type is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient, multipartform-data

setup :
using Angular 6

http version - "@angular/http": "^6.1.9",

I tried to post csv file using multipart form data as header but it makes request failed. It seems that Browser always sends the content-type as "application-json". **I tried many approach which was given on the internet to change the content type but nothing works.** Some of them i tried are **set content type as undefined which throws error in http.js file**,let the browser detect so **ignored setting the content type** that also failed. Please help me on this

```
groupBulkUpload(file) {  
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    // commented the below lines
    // formData.append('file', file, { type: 'text/csv' }));
    // let header = new HttpHeaders()
    // .set("Content-Type" , `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`)
    // let options = { headers: header };

    let url = this.getAnyConfigUrl("rate");
    return this.http.post(url,formData)
  }

 //calling the api
 const blob = new Blob([csvData]);
    var f = new File([blob] , "filename.csv", {type: 'text/csv', lastModified: new Date().getDate()})
    this._config.groupBulkUpload(f).subscribe(val=>{
      console.log(val)
    })
```

Updated : Browser always take it as a Json type. So it could not able to detect
the CSV format that's my guess. Any Idea ?

Request Headers:
[image]

Request Payload:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you are using interceptor to intercept the http request and add the `JSON` datatype.

You are missing the third parameter in append method (which is optional) but you can pass file name as third argument. For files `formData.append` you can pass file name as 3rd argument. if we omit the third argument for `blob` type then the default file name will be `blob`.

**Parameters:**

> **name**
>   The name of the field whose data is contained in value.
>
> **value**
>   The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.
>
> **filename Optional**
>   The filename reported to the server (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter. The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

Try this and remove this call from interceptor.

```
groupBulkUpload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, "filename.csv");
    let url = this.getAnyConfigUrl("rate");
    return this.http.post(url, formData);
}
//calling the api
const blob = new Blob([csvData]);
var f = new File([blob], "filename.csv", { type: 'text/csv', lastModified: new Date().getDate() })
this._config.groupBulkUpload(f).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val)
})
```

Comment: request getting failed. Since browser detecting the content as JSON instead of CSV/ Multipart formdata

Comment: content-type not changing, still it goes like json

Comment: Are you using any interceptor?

Comment: Hey, Yes let me check it there once.

Comment: You are just awesome. Thanks for saving my life. I just rewrite and tried tons of time no luck but you found it very easilty. Thanks again.